# Firebase Authentication - sendEmailVerification - This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, vercel

I have an application to react that when I click on the mail verification link that is sent by firebase, in local it works correctly.
But in the vercel display it shows me the following:

> Error encountered
> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

```
const configuration = {
  url: URL_LOGIN,
};

await sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser, configuration)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(
      `A verification email has been sent to ${name}.`
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(
      "Error sending verification email.",
      error
    );
  });
```

I hope that when I click on the verification link that firebase sends, it will verify the email and then redirect to my login page.

Comment: Are you sure URL_LOGIN is defined and contains the value you expect?